# Does Ruby uniq works on an array of hashes with nested elements

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes and in each of those hashes I have a nested structure like so:

```
{
        "id" : "RZ60586_5836f1ed468e5d0004000015",
        "status" : "live",
        "phases" : [
            {
                "phase" : "main_phase",
                "elements" : [
                    {
                        "banner_id" : "5836f1ed468e5d0004000015_widesky_light",
                        "split_var" : "light",
                        "reports" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                        "banner_id" : "5836f1ed468e5d0004000015_widesky_light",
                        "split_var" : "light",
                        "reports" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                        "banner_id" : "5836f1ed468e5d0004000015_widesky_light",
                        "split_var" : "light",
                        "reports" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                        "banner_id" : "5836f1ed468e5d0004000015_widesky_light",
                        "split_var" : "light",
                        "reports" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                        "banner_id" : "5836f1ed468e5d0004000015_widesky_light",
                        "split_var" : "light",
                        "reports" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                        "banner_id" : "5836f1ed468e5d0004000015_widesky_light",
                        "split_var" : "dark",
                        "reports" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                        "banner_id" : "5836f1ed468e5d0004000015_widesky_light",
                        "split_var" : "dark",
                        "reports" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                        "banner_id" : "5836f1ed468e5d0004000015_widesky_light",
                        "split_var" : "dark",
                        "reports" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                        "banner_id" : "5836f1ed468e5d0004000015_widesky_light",
                        "split_var" : "dark",
                        "reports" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                        "banner_id" : "5836f1ed468e5d0004000015_widesky_light",
                        "split_var" : "dark",
                        "reports" : [ ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

This is an example of a hash that will be inside of an array. If I use `uniq` on this array (the variation in it will happen only inside the `reports` array):

```
{
                        "banner_id" : "5836f1ed468e5d0004000015_widesky_light",
                        "split_var" : "dark",
                        "reports" : [ ]
                    }
```

So, the question is, how confident can I be that I'll not lose any data while using `uniq`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays and hashes, when tested for equality (which `uniq` does) are compared element by element.

Two arrays are considered equal if their respective elements are equal. Two hashes are considered equal when they have the same set of keys and each key's value is equal to that in the other hash.

So, if `reports` values will be different, `uniq` won't drop your hashes.

Answer (score 1):

[Array#`uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq)

> compares values using their [`hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-hash) and [`eql?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-eql-3F) methods for efficiency.

So the answer your question

> how confident can I be that I'll not loose any data while using uniq

lies in how `uniq` works. Write some tests, play with `hash` and `eql?` methods to be sure (and see @Sergio's answer on the order of hash comparison).